# Criar um array com os dados de um xls

Tags: vb.net

Recebo valores de um xls que quero que sejam armazenados num classe que tem um array para posteriormente os listar
alguem me sabe dizer como se faz?

Podem ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, tente ser mais claro. Você pode [edit] e adicionar mais detalhes a sua pergunta a qualquer momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, primeiramente você terá que fazer referência ao Excel Library no seu projeto, depois disso você consegue pegar os dados que estão no arquivo xls. Abaixo tem um link que descreve como fazer isso com vb .net. Achei melhor passar o link doque colocar o código aqui.

[Manipulando arquivos Excel sem uso da interoperabilidade ou conexão OLEDB](http://raphaelcardoso.com.br/criar-ler-e-modificar-arquivos-excel-sem-uso-da-interoperabilidade-ou-conexao-oledb/)

```
if (fupArquivo.HasFile)
{
  // Recebe o arquivo em array de bytes
  byte[] buffer = fupArquivo.FileBytes;
  // Criar o arquivo em memoria
  System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
  // Carrega o WorkBook do Excel
  ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Workbook workbook = ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Workbook.Load(stream);
  // Recupera o primeiro WorkSheet
  ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

  // Cria uma tabela para armazenar o Excel
  System.Data.DataTable dtExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();
  dtExcel.Columns.Add("Coluna0", typeof(string));
  dtExcel.Columns.Add("Coluna1", typeof(string));

  // Percorre as linhas do Excel
  for (int rowIndex = worksheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; rowIndex <= worksheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
  {
       // Recupera a linha do Excel
       ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet.Row row = worksheet.Cells.GetRow(rowIndex);

       // Adiciona os dados na tabela
       System.Data.DataRow newRow = dtExcel.NewRow();
       newRow["Coluna0"] = row.GetCell(0).StringValue;
       newRow["Coluna1"] = row.GetCell(1).StringValue;
       dtExcel.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }
}
}
```

Referência: http://raphaelcardoso.com.br/criar-ler-e-modificar-arquivos-excel-sem-uso-da-interoperabilidade-ou-conexao-oledb/

Comment: Na verdade era melhor colocar aqui um código de exemplo.